# Shadow blocks in Beamer

Tags: beamer, themes

Some beamer themes such as Berlin, Warsaw use shadow environment for theorems, definitions, proofs. How can I get rid of it and have the same look as in CambridgeUS for example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using

```
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
```

you can get ride of the shadow around the boxes and redefining the `block title` color you can suppress the color for the title. An example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{PaloAlto}

\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=false]
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=structure,bg=white}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{theorem}
test
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

[image]